# Finalize operator not called when wrapped

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using a angular service to wrap some of my http calls in order to manage the loading state of my application.

This service stores the status of the calls for further process. Unfortunately the finalize function is never called.

Here is the wrapper:

```
searchWithLoader(obs: Observable<any>) {
   this.show();
   obs.pipe(finalize(() => {
      console.log("FINALIZE NOT CALLED");
      this.hide();
   }));

   return obs;
}
```

And the way I typically call it :

```
   let performanceLoader = this.loaderService.searchWithLoader(
      this.performanceDataService.getSomething({
        x: x,
        y: y,
      }));

    performanceLoader.subscribe(() => {});
```

Is there a way around this in order for the finalize to be called in a service instead of the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the pipe function of the obserable it doesn't mutate the observable. Instead, it returns a new observable. So you should set obs to obs.pipe() like below

```
searchWithLoader(obs: Observable<any>) {
   this.show();
   return obs.pipe(finalize(() => {
      console.log("FINALIZE NOT CALLED");
      this.hide();
   }));      
}
```

Comment: You could even just return obs.pipe() and remove the return line at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
 this.performanceDataService.getSomething({
        x: x,
        y: y,
      }))
```

It's not an observable, it need to be an observable when you pass it to the `searchWithLoader` function. UNLESS you can show the code fo the `getSomething` we can help you more

Comment: getSomething is a API call generated by a raml file so you can 100% consider it as an observable